# Find pattern in regular expression using C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like this:

```
string str = "Property first {prop1=val1;prop2=val2}this is reg table[uvm]dsfhsjhsdj[/uvm]this is uvm test{pp1=vv2}";
```

And I need to get [uvm]...[/uvm] string.

I have tried this:

```
reg = new Regex(@"(\[uvm\].*?\[\\uvm\])");
string s = reg.Match(str).Groups[0].Value;
```

But it is not working. It does not match. What should I do?

Comment: http://regexr.com/ this site is good to try regex strings

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the *Regular Expression*, but rather the string `input`.

You input contains `[/uvm]` and not `[\uvm]` which of course won't be matched by the *Regular Expression*.

Also, I would suggest you to move the Capture to catch the inside of `uvm`, by simply moving the parenthesis inside the `regex`, like this:

```
\[uvm\](.*?)\[\\uvm\]
```

Comment: @SUMEETvishwas, Glad to help. It's customary to UpVote, Accept, helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

The regex you're using is a little off - you're using the wrong type of slash, try this:

```
var reg = new Regex(@"(\[uvm\].*?\[\/uvm\])");
```

Also note that if you want to retrieve the text within the `[uvm]` tags, you would need an additional group. Here's a working example:

```
var str = "Property first {prop1=val1;prop2=val2}this is reg table[uvm]dsfhsjhsdj[/uvm]this is uvm test{pp1=vv2}";
var reg = new Regex(@"(\[uvm\](.*?)\[\/uvm\])");

var m1 = reg.Match(str).Groups[1].Value; // = "[uvm]dsfhsjhsdj[/uvm]"
var m2 = reg.Match(str).Groups[2].Value; // = "dsfhsjhsdj"
```

[**Working example**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/r86G9Z)

The accessing of the groups would obviously need to be much more robust - this is purely for demonstrative purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to set any capturing groups and get your value using `Regex.Match(str).Value` if you use [**look-arounds**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
string str = "Property first {prop1=val1;prop2=val2}this is reg table[uvm]dsfhsjhsdj[/uvm]this is uvm test{pp1=vv2}";
Regex rx = new Regex(@"(?<=\[uvm]).*?(?=\[/uvm])");
foreach (Match m in rx.Matches(str))
{
   Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

Or, you can get all matches using LINQ:

```
var matches = rx.Matches(str).Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Value).ToList();
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/KCgIZJ)

**REGEX EXPLANATION**:

- `(?<=\[uvm])` - A positive look-behind making sure there is literal `[uvm]` string *before* our expected result
- `.*?` - Any string of characters (except newline, if you need `.` to match a newline, add `RegexOptions.Singleline` flag in the Regex declaration) as few as possible (due to `*?` lazy quantifier)
- `(?=\[/uvm])` - A positive look-ahead that makes sure there is literal `[/uvm]` *after* our expected result.

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%5C%5Buvm%5D).*%3F(%3F%3D%5C%5B%2Fuvm%5D)&i=Property%20first%20%7Bprop1%3Dval1%3Bprop2%3Dval2%7Dthis%20is%20reg%20table%5Buvm%5Ddsfhsjhsdj%5B%2Fuvm%5Dthis%20is%20uvm%20test%7Bpp1%3Dvv2%7D)